# ubuntu+apache2+ispconfig3+roundcube. Проблема в настройке

Tags: ubuntu, apache, nginx, postfix, roundcube

Здесь https://www.howtoforge.com/using-roundcube-webmail-with-ispconfig-3-on-debian-wheezy-nginx расписано как установить roundcube когда используется nginx. У меня просто apache2. Я так понимаю, что различия будут в п.3. Подскажите, что там нужно прописать?

Comment: Здесь https://www.howtoforge.com/using-roundcube-webmail-with-ispconfig-3-on-debian-wheezy-apache2 как настраивать без nginx